# Скроллинг ListView с изображениями

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml, xmlhttprequest

Я использую Qt 5.9.4, QtCreator for Windows, MinGW compiler.

Я использую QML компонент - ListView для вывода сообщений чата через делегат.
Задача в проскролливании ListView в самый конец (в моем случае вниз).
В обычном случае, когда сообщение содержит только текст без ссылок, используется listView.positionViewAtEnd() и работает хорошо, но при наличии в делегате изображений этот вариант работает плохо.

### Описание проблемы:

Для вывода изображений в делегате используется XMLHttpRequest. Так как изображения приходят в виде ссылок, требуется проверка - изображение это или файл:

```
function ifUrlFile(url, callback)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('HEAD', url, true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(xhr.status === 200)
            {
                var myHeader = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type");
                var isWeb = myHeader.startsWith("text/html");
                callback(isWeb === false); //!isWeb
            }
            else
                callback(false);
        }
    }
}
```

В итоге ссылка на изображение вставляется в свойство source у блока Image делегата.

```
 Image {
            id: messageImage
            visible: (mainBlock.isUrlFile ? true : false)
            source:{
                if(mainBlock.isUrlFile)
                {
                    if(mainBlock.isImage())
                    {
                        return model.text;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return mainBlock.getFileIcon();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        }
```

- Мое предположение:

Теперь при вызове  listView.positionViewAtEnd() позиция устанавливается верно. Затем происходит работа скрипта и обработчика xhr.onreadystatechange, картинки подгружаются, а позиция меняется куда-то в середину экрана или загрузившегося изображения. Если сделать xhr запрос синхронным, то изображения вообще не появляются. *Пример ошибки. Позиция на середине изображения после нажатия кнопки scrollButton:*
[image: Баг. Позиция на середине изображения]

- А требуется установить положение ровно вниз до конца последнего элемента по нажатию кнопки

  ```
  Button {
  id: scrollButton

  function scrollToBottom() {
        var newIndex = listView.count - 1;// last index
        listView.positionViewAtEnd();
        listView.currentIndex = newIndex;
      }

  onClicked: {
      scrollToBottom();
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: ниче не понял. Если речь о положении картинки на экране, то причем тут AJAX, проверка на isImage и др... А где html, ?

Comment: Функция ifUrlFile() используется для получения типа файла из ссылки на этот файл. Отображение картинки происходит в QML компоненте Image, в который передается ссылка на изображение в параметр source.

Comment: `listView.positionViewAtIndex(newIndex, ListView.End)`

Comment: А ещё добавьте обработчик в Image `onStatusChanged:{}`, и в нём, когда статус будет `Status.Ready`, попробуйте повторить манипуляции по скроллингу в конец. У вас просто после загрузки меняются размеры делегата. Уже после того, как кнопка отработала

Comment: Ну либо delegate написан так, что qml не может корректно определить его размеры и соответственно не скроллит корректно. Вы бы привели минимальный пример, воспроизводящий проблему. Так очень трудно понять, в чём проблема